# Django prefix on all generated URLs

Tags: django-admin

My proxy (nginx public port 80) to django (gunicorn wsgi localhost port 8000) strips off the path to the application "/app" so requests for `http://server/app/hello` appears to django as `/hello` and requests for `http://server/app/admin` appears to django as `/admin`.

The problem is that the admin site generates output with absolute URLs such as `<form action="/admin/"...` in the login screen.  So the user sees the admin login screen but it posts to `http://server/admin` which doesn't exist.  (I kind of hoped it would use relative URLs and work at any location.)

What is the simplest way to get the admin pages to universally prepend "/app" like `form action="/app/admin/"` to all URLs it generates in page output?  I am hoping for something built into Django like a simple define, and not having to create special filters then rewrite templates to use them, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See documentation for FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name

Set that to be '/app' instead of default of None.

Comment: Thanks, you make life easier for the rest of us! :-)

Comment: Does this work in django admin&media? I tried using this, but django admin and the media is still redirected to `http://server/admin`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to write your own wsgi dispatcher, like one below

```
def application(environ, request_response):
  # do whatever you want with path

  sys.path.append(path_to_django_project)
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'proj_name.settings'

  # pass control to django
  import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  app_entry_point = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
  return app_entry_point(environ,request_response)
```