# reverse proxy nginx rewrite uwsgi redirect response of location

Tags: django, redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy, uwsgi

My configuration now is nginx + uwsgi + different django apps.

My configuration for nginx is configure as follow:

```
location /app1/ {
    uwsgi_pass  app1;
    include     /home/code/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
}

location /app2/ {
    uwsgi_pass  app2;
    include     /home/code/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
}
```

and I also set the mount point in uwsgi in order to make the reverse proxy works.

something like this:

```
mount = /app1=app1.wsgi:application
manage-script-name = true
```

because my app require login before access the content of the website.

So when I type www.example.com/app1

Uwsgi will return a 302 redirection response back:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 10:30:47 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: /login/?next=/app1/
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Vary: Cookie
```

Nginx will follow the link in location, however, because this location is not /app1/login/?next=/app1/ so it is unable to send the request to uwsgi. Instead, it trys to find login/?next=/app1/ locally in its root.

How can I rewrite the redirect response with correct prefix? Should configure on nginx side or on uwsgi side?

Comment: I think your django app needs to know that it lives at /app1 so it can create that login redirect link appropriately. Looks like here is a similar question that answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826846/2599940

Comment: @kevswanberg thank you for your tips. I now have another question. It looks like I can let my django app knows that it lives at /app1, does that mean if I set properly for django project, I don't need the mount point and set script name in uwsgi, if django knows that it lives at /app1?

Comment: No because you are using some of the URL's path to route in nginx.